# Is Federated Identity Management possible using Azure AD or Azure B2C?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2b

Website webapp1.com has registered users with its own IdP implementation.

There are other websites such as webapp2.com, webapp3.com, webapp4.com (different domain).

A logged-in-user user1 of webapp1.com wants to do a SSO login to webapp2.com or webapp3.com or webapp4.com.
user1 has accounts in webapp2.com/webapp3.com/webapp4.com as well.

Is there a way to implement this using Azure AD or Azure AD B2C?

This is possible using PingIdentity.
https://www.pingidentity.com/en/resources/blog/posts/2021/sso-vs-federated-identity-management.html

Tried Azure AD and Azure AD B2C.
There is no documentation found how this could be done.

Comment: I think you could do this with Azure AD. Webapp2-4 could use AAD as their IdP. Webapp1 could offer AAD login as one of the options. You could also setup SCIM (user provisioning) to provision users from AAD to Webapp1 (since it is its own IdP as well). Sorry if I've misunderstood something in your scenario.

Comment: Adding some more details for more clarity.
User1 of WebApp1 has an account either with the id i.e. "User1" or "User12" with WebApp2. Similarly, the same user i.e. User1 of WebApp1 may have account in WebApp2-4.
The question is if User1 is authentication in WebApp1, can the same User1 be SSO'ed into WebApp2-4 as well.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the web apps connect to the same identity provider/s, the user will get SSO if they visit another app and pass through those same identity providers. With AAD this is the default and only behaviour. With AAD B2C this is the default behaviour, but can be restricted.

Answer (score 0):

Federated Identity is now available in Azure AD https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/workload-identity-federation

It's called Workload Identity Federation. You can follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/workload-identity-federation-create-trust?pivots=identity-wif-apps-methods-azp) to configure an app to trust an external identity provider.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).